# I can't change the colors of my nav links

Tags: css, navigationbar

What does my css need to look like in order to change the color of the nav links to white?

Here is my code

```
      <div class="col-sm-12">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
 <div class="container-fluid">
<div class="navbar-header">
  <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>                        
  </button>
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">Tile Works</a>
</div>
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li><a href="services.html">Services</a></li>
    <li><a href="gallery.html">Photo Gallery</a></li>
    <li><a href="about.html">About Us</a></li>
    <li><a href="contact.html">Contact Us</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
</div>
</nav>
</div>
```

Comment: can you add the css codes?

Answer (score 1):

You can use css code like below:

```
.navbar-collapse .navbar-nav li a {
  color: white;
}
```

I tried and it works.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this

```
 .collapse navbar-collapse.nav navbar-nav > li > a {
            color: #777;
        }
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

```
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>li a {color:#fff;}
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.